Cannot run dapr sidecar
I am facing this issue when running dapr init command:

failed to move dashboard files: rename C:\Users\test\.dapr\bin\release\windows_amd64\web C:\Users\test\.dapr\bin\web: Access is denied.

I am new to dapr and trying to install and initialize it.
When I use dapr init command, it shows something like this:

I can see all the containers are installed and running in docker as well.
But when I run dapr run --app-id myapp --dapr-http-port 3500 command, it shows me this error:

Zexec: C:\Users\test\.dapr\bin\daprd.exe": file does not exist


And this is how my .dapr folder looks like:

I tried reinstalling everything, like dapr including all the containers and restarting the system but nothing works.
